# When div is clicked, check corresponding radio input jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, radio-button

Here's my problem, I want an entire div to be click able, when clicked I need the radio button contained in the div to be checked, so the div acts as a radio itself. Here's what I thought I could use;

`$('#content').click(function(e) { 
$('input:radio[name="id_"]').prop('checked', true);
});`

But this is not selecting the relative radio inside the div. I think I can use a `this` selector, am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

building on Deif's solution this will toggle the checked status when clicking on the div

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XSNLz/1/)

```
<div id="content">
    Some content
    <input type="radio" id="radio1" value="test" />
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$('#content').click(function () {    
   var val =  $(this).find('input:radio').prop('checked')?false:true;
   $(this).find('input:radio').prop('checked', val);
});
</script>
```

Comment: I picked this because the code is precisely what I wanted! Though i will incorporate @Arindam's code in here to fine tune this! Thanks a lot to you for the fiddle too.

Answer (score 4):

You don't give any code, so I guess:

### DEMO

[See my demo on CodePen](http://codepen.io/ByScripts/pen/hmwEc)

### HTML

```
<div class="content">
  <input type="radio" name="foo">
</div>

<div class="content">
  <input type="radio" name="foo">
</div>

<div class="content">
  <input type="radio" name="foo">
</div>
```

### CSS (for example)

```
.content {
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  padding-top: 100px;
  background-color: #eee;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

### JS (JQUERY)

```
$('.content').click(function(){
  $(this).find('input[type=radio]').prop('checked', true);
})
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can use the `this` selector. I have made a quick [jsfiddle to show you an example](http://jsfiddle.net/XSNLz/10/).

Comment: I like this solution, but you can also re-do it so that the radio is checked/unchecked (i.e. the selection is inverted) when `click()` happens.

Answer (score 2):

This should do it.

```
$('input:radio[name*="id_"]'), assuming the name starts with id_
```

And yes you can use `this`. Use it to filter down its children like:

`$(this).children('input:radio[name*=id_]').prop("checked", true)`

The  key is using `name*=id_`

This means select element whose name starts with `id_`. Isn't that what you wanted ?

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#content').click(function(){
$(this).children('radio').attr('checked','checked')
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with this:

```
$('div').click(function(){
     if( $('div').find('input:checkbox').prop("checked") == true){
         $('div').find('input:checkbox').prop("checked", false);
     }
     else{
         $('div').find('input:checkbox').prop("checked", true);
     }
});
```

[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sohelkhalifa/8mS2R/15/)